# Checkbox Checking requirements

Tags: windows-phone-7, checkbox

I am new to coding and I would like to set a requirement to allow certain check box to be selected only after the requirement is met.
lets say I have 2 check boxes, A and B.
How do I set to only allow to check B only after A is checked.
The initial status of the wedwebcheckbox and wedcupcheckbox is Null
And also, is there any way to wrap the text on the check box?

```
private void wedThemecheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (wedThemecheckBox == Checked)
    {
        wedWebcheckBox.IsChecked = false;
        wedCupcheckBox.IsChecked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        wedWebcheckBox.IsChecked = null;
        wedCupcheckBox.IsChecked = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: CheckboxB.Ischecked=true; on checkboxA_Checked Event?

Answer (score 0):

For disabling controls use the `IsEnabled` property. When set to false, control cannot be edited. In this case, that means that the checkbox cannot be checked at all by user.

Answer (score 0):

Keep Checkbox B's IsHitTestVisible to False(This makes checkbox B visible but not operable) and on checkbox A's Checked event

set

```
chbxB.IsHitTestVisible=true;
```

now you can use(operate) chbxB.

Hope it helps.